# How to avoid discontinuity in periodical HTTP request by jQuery?

Tags: ajax, http, jquery

I am new to jQuery and want to use it to retrieve data from a server every 3 seconds. The web server sends data every 3 seconds in JSON format. The JSON data contains a numerical array field { "samples" : [10,15,-7,19,34,...] }. I wrote the following jQuery ajax request to retrieve data from the server every 3 seconds:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            myData = data.samples;
            setTimeout(getData, 3000);
        },
        dataType : 'json'
    });

    return myData;
}
```

However, due to timing jitter, the data sent from the server may not get updated precisely at every 3 seconds. So how should I write the jQuery ajax request to avoid the possible data discontinuity? That is, I want the returned myData contains all fresh new data array elements from each getData() call and does not contain duplicated or missing data samples due to possible timing jitter.

Comment: Do you have any data that can uniquely identify your atomic data? That way, you can send last retrieved data's id, and make the server send from next one onwards.

Comment: By "timing jitter", do you mean that the data on the server may refreshed slightly slower or be in the process of being refreshed when you make the request?

Comment: No there is not time stamp information sent from the server. By "time jitter", any situations can occur: Either the server may refresh slightly slower than 3 seconds or be in the process of being refreshed when you make the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the last timestamp that the data was updated on the server along with the other JSON array.  Then, when it is time to request data again using your jQuery call, check the timestamp against what you already have.  This will give you a way to know if it is the same data, or if it has been refreshed.

Comment: If the server doesn't send any time stamp information for the most recent refresh, is there a way in client side to do this?

Comment: @tonga not without some way of uniquely identifying the set of information returned, as Andre mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need pass around more info.  Include another field in your AJAX called "lastUpdate" with a timestamp.  Your javascript can save the last timestamp it got and provide it to the server.  The server responds only with samples after that timestamp (so you don't miss any) and won't respond with anything if its still up to date (so you don't duplicate).

Comment: So does that mean that there is no way to do this without changing the server side?

Answer (score 1):

There's little point returning `myData`. (a) the variable is not declared within the function, and (b) the data arrives asynchronously from the server.

As it stands, `getData()` is guaranteed (at best) to return the data obtained at the *previous* iteration.

To work with the freshly obtained data, you need to do whatever is necessary with `myData` within the `success` function or in a `done()` callback, as follows :

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        var myData = data.samples;
        //Do whatever is necessary with myData here.
        //Call extenal function as necessary to do the job.
        setTimeout(getData, 3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: I forgot that myData is local in my original post.

Comment: The scope of `myData` is somewhat academic. The point is, you can't return it from `getData()` as if everything was synchronous.

Comment: If I return myData from function getData() as in the original post, why does it return the previous obtained data, not the newest data? Say if I use in the following way

a = getData();

Will "a" be the latest data array I get from polling the server? Sorry I'm not familiar with the mechanism of Ajax.

Comment: The first "A" of "AJAX" stands for "Asynchronous", meaning that the code that makes the HTTP request won't wait for the HTTP response before continuing to the next statement - in your code that next statement will be `return myData`. The server response will arrive a short time *later*; at that time the `success` (or `done`) function will fire. So the order of execution of statements is not the order in which they appear in the function. If you still don't get it, then do some background reading on the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code, with particular regard to AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in such a way that takes advantage of the asynchronous nature of ajax. For example,

```
var interval;
function handleData(data) {
    // I handle the data returned from the ajax request.
    console.log(data);
}
function getData() {
    // I send the ajax request.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        success: handleData,
        error: function(){
            // on error, stop making requests to help with debugging.
            console.log(arguments);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
}
interval = setInterval(getData,3000);
```

This will result that in most cases, the responses will come in order. You can make that true in all cases if you get rid of the interval and instead call get data 3 seconds after the previous success.

```
function getData() {
    // I send the ajax request.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        success: handleData,
        error: function(){
            // on error, stop making requests to help with debugging.
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });
}
function handleData(data) {
    // I handle the data returned from the ajax request.
    console.log(data);
    setTimeout(getData,3000);
}
getData();
```

Side note: the "timing jitter" isn't a jitter at all, it's simply a logic error. The data is always one set behind due to Ajax being Asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for correction. By "time jitter", I mean I don't want to have missing or duplicated samples between two Ajax requests. It's fine that I get a delayed array from JSON, but just no missing or duplicate samples. Based on the above responses, seems that I need to add some information in JSON on the server side.

Comment: @tonga you shouldn't need to add any additional information, if the error callback never gets called, you never missed a response. Duplicates would only happen if the server itself returns duplicates, you won't get two responses from one request.

Comment: @KevinB I believe the actual issue here is duplicates may be returned from the server side.  Your example is a good one though, for general implementation aside from that issue.